# Can anyone identify this screw from a Dell computer?

Tags: electrical, bolts

[image: Dell SSD screw]

It's from a Dell computer so not exactly home improvement but hopefully not too far off topic. I would guess it's metric, being tech, so I assumed it was an M1.4 given the shaft is about 1.4mm across. However when I ordered some M1.4 bolts from an eBay vendor they are smaller than this. I now don't know if I mis-identified the bolt or if the vendor has sent the wrong size.

**Later:**

Thanks for all the comments and answers. I had hoped the rather crude picture would be enough to identify the screw, but I guess I would need more accurate measurements that I cannot do since I don't have the equipment. I will take the advice in the answer and look for a set of computer screws that look as if they cover the size range and hope I get lucky.

Comment: Hardware stores like Lowes or Home Depot usually have a board where you can insert the screws to see what size they are.  But given its a computer screw, knowing what it mounts to usually would give you the information you need to look for.  I would guess that is a hard drive mounting screw.

Comment: (a) *screw*, not bolt; (b) what are you actually trying to do? Do you have 2 places where these go and you lost 1 screw and need another? Or something else? If it is to replace a missing screw, computer model -> online service manual -> parts diagram will provide the exact answer.

Comment: Based on the collection of hardware I have from disassembled computer & peripherals, my WAG would be it's a #6-32 or #8-32.  I would not automatically assume it's metric just 'cause it's "tech".

Comment: And what's the bolt/screw out of?  Length may not be critical in some applications (like fastening a motherboard to the chassis), but very important in other places (like a hard disk drive).

Comment: Is it a case screw and/or a disk attachment screw?  Both of those are pretty standardized...

Comment: Looks like a drive mounting screw. If that's the case, then you need to replace it with another drive mount screw - if they're too long they either won't hold or they'll damage the drive when you try to force it in too far.

Comment: If it is indeed a drive mount screw, and it does look that way, I have found that a drive in a tray with 4 holes works just as well if you only use 2 or 3 screws, it won't vibrate too much if you tighten them properly, and if it's an SSD you can just stick it in place with double sided tape or something.

Comment: If a disk drive vibrates at all, something's wrong with it.

Comment: This answer lists all the standard computer screw sizes and where they're used:  https://superuser.com/a/1496280/15990

Comment: @FreeMan - I agree. It should be fairly easy to tell by unscrewing another drive mounting screw from the same case and comparing.

Comment: @SteveSh - All mechanical HDDs vibrate to some extent. Often you can hear them making a faint humming or buzzing sound as they spin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its not necessarily metric, many things in computers are imperial, that's why we talk about 2.5" hard drives and 32" monitors.

Computer bolts are a mess. Because of this, our it-technician has a box of all types of bolts, clips, retainers etc. that he encountered at work.

**To answer your question in a strict sense:**

You need a thread pitch gauge (to measure the pitch) and a caliper gauge (to measure the outside dimensions). Pitch, outside diameter and length identify the bolt.

**To answer your question in a practical sense:**

I'd buy a "computer screw set" online. If necessary, replace "computer" with "dell laptop" or "hard disk". It is possible that the first try won't succeed.

Another approach would be to ask at the next computer service point.
I'd avoid the hardware stores: "Exotic" sizes are usually only available on back-order, and then only as an entire box.

Answer (score 10):

If you know the computer model, you don't even need to measure the screws, just google "Dell <model> service manual".

In the section "Removing and Installing Components" of said document appears a  list of all the screw types used on that particular model.

e.g., for a (randomly selected) Latitude 3420 [image: Part of table]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's at least a M1.6-.35. 42mm was 817 pixels giving us a pixel size around .039mm. I measured it with a major diameter around 43 to 45 pixels wide. 44 pixels is around 1.71mm. Since the screw doesn't look to be on the paper, I'm assuming it looks a bit bigger than it is. Searches for M1.6 screw dell laptop came up with a few results. Didn't get anything specific when changing the size to M1.7